# Setting src attribute on create element from fetched image(s)

Tags: javascript, api

I have fetched data from an API called Randomuser which passes random users with images included. I've selected the names and the phone numbers of 5 random users.

With the images included but the images are the same image which has to be randomized.

Any way of randomizing the images?

My code:

```js
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=us').then(response => {
return response.json();
}).then(responseJson => {
  responseJson.results
  console.log(responseJson);

  for (const user of responseJson.results) {
    const img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.innertext = user.picture.medium;
    -- > img.setAttribute("src", "img.setAttribute("
      src ", "
      https: //randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/5.jpg")")
      img.setAttribute("width", "50"); img.setAttribute("height", "50"); img.setAttribute("alt", ""); document.body.appendChild(img)

      console.log(user);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Randomized or taken from the user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace :

```
img.setAttribute("src", "img.setAttribute("src",
```

"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/5.jpg")")

By :

```
img.setAttribute("src", user.picture.medium);
```

**Sample example :**

```js
$.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=us', function(responseJson) {
  for (const user of responseJson.results) {
    const img = document.createElement("IMG");

    img.innertext = user.picture.medium;
    img.setAttribute("src", user.picture.medium);
    img.setAttribute("width", "50");
    img.setAttribute("height", "50");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "");

    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you.

I had tried this but it showed no response thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, Does the snippet here works fine for you ?

Comment: Oh no it's already fixed i meant that the snippet is working.

Comment: Ahh so glad to help brother, happy coding.